# MVC3 - Model empty on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two models - category and article. I have pretty much the same delete views and controllers for both of them. The only difference is that it works for categories, but with articles I get empty model on HttpPost.

Categories:

```
    public ActionResult DeleteCat(int id)
    {
        Category cat = db.CategoryByID(id);
        if (cat != null)
        {
            return View(cat);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteCat(Category model)
    {
        db.DeleteCategory(model.CategoryID);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Articles:

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Article art = db.ArticleByID(id);
        if (art != null)
        {
            return View(art);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Article model)
    {
        db.DeleteArticle(model.ArticleID);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Both views are generated by Visual Studio and I haven't changed them. When I want to delete a category, everything goes well. But when I want to delete an article, it first gets selected properly from database, then the view is displayed (everything is OK) but when I click the delete button the model is empty (all properties are either 0, null or false) and so the db.DeleteArticle throws an exception (there's no article with ArticleID = 0). Could anyone please provide me with any hints as to what should I check or how should I work around this?

Comment: What does your Article class look like?

Comment: Yes, and like @SLaks says, you can add a parameter to your HttpPost Delete action a la `FormCollection coll`.  Once posted, you can inspect the collection to see all of the keys/values that were posted with the form.

Comment: have a look at the function call `db.ArticleByID(id)` - is it returning a valid object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two primary ways this can happen.

One way is that you have custom model binding that is not working. I assume you are doing everything out-of-the-box so this wouldn't apply.

The most likely issue is that the data is not getting POSTed. Ensure that the fields exist *inside* the same Form that the Delete button is POSTing.

Answer (score 23):

If the parameter for the model in the `[HttpPost]` Action is the same name as a property in the model it'll be null and will fail validation saying the field was invalid.

Example:

```
public class ContactMessage 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string sankdmfskm { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ContactMessage sankdmfskm)
{
...
}
```

`sankdmfskm` will be `null`.

Tested in MVC3 and MVC4.

Answer (score 14):

Had same problem. One of my properties in the model was called *model*

```
public String model { get; set; }
```

After renaming the property to *myModel*. The model object stopped coming back null in ActionResult

Comment: This is really random! I can't believe a bug like this exists, and hasn't been resolved yet!

Comment: My parameter was called name, and caused the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! Had similar issue here and was pulling my hair out because I couldn't get it to work. Your answer lead me to the right direction. I was using something like public ShippingDetails ShippingDetails and couldn't figure out why I had problems on postback.

Comment: Same happened to me, my property was called "Usuario". Thanks @adinas!

Answer (score 12):

Ensure that your model is marking it's properties as properties (if using VB, or C# with get/set), not a public field... MVC won't map to a public field, but will to the public property.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. I did in your case

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ContactMessage sankdmfskm)
{
UpdateModel(sankdmfskm);
...
}
```

After model was updated it returned me proper values and not null anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I'm adding an answer to this because it differs from the others and someone may find it useful.

I had a BaseViewModel as I was using multiple models in one view.

On my Controller Action instead of passing the BaseViewModel (and the parameters like model.RegistrationModel.Username) I passed RegistrationFormModel so it was not binding to the BaseViewModel I was using in my view

see img - the problem I had was that I was passing the RegistrationModel into the Post action instead of the BaseAuthenticationModel (which holds the RegistrationModel) used in the View. So binding wasn't happening correctly